# R string split on parentheses, keeping the parentheses in the split with its content

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I am trying to split strings of a format

`x <- "A(B)C"`

where A, B and C could be empty strings or any sets of characters except for parentheses. The parentheses are always there - I want to keep them around the characters they enclose, so that the result would be:

`"A" "(B)" "C"`

So far my best try was:

```
strsplit(x, "(?<=\\))|(?=\\()", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "A"  "("  "B)" "C"
```

but that keeps the opening parenthesis separate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
x <- "A(B)C"
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "\\([^()]*\\)|[^()]+")
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/ZLZgM0) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ybIzY/1). *Details*:

- `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
- `|` - or
- `[^()]+` - one or more chars other than `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)

x <- c("A(B)C", "ABC", "0$b")
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[\\(]?.{1}[\\)]?")

# [[1]]
# [1] "A"   "(B)" "C"  
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "0" "$" "b"
```